# How to pass Ajax params to controller in ASP.NET Core

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, routes, jquery-select2

I created a select with [select2 js](http://select2.org) and created the ajax request:

```
$('#slcCidade').select2({
    ajax: {
        type:'POST',
        url: '/get-cidade',
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        data: function (params) {
            var query = {
                search: params.term
            }
            return query;
        },
        processResults: function (data) {

            return {
                results: data.items
            };
        }
    }
});
```

In my controller I have the following method to get data, then it returns to my page:

```
 [Route("get-cidade/{search:regex(^[[a-zA-Z]])}")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> GetCidade(string search)
    {
        var lstCidadesVM = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CidadeViewModel>>(await _cidadeBLL.GetByNome(search));
        return new JsonResult(new { Data = lstCidadesVM });
    }
```

The request never returns to my controller and analyzing the request I see that a 404 error has occurred

```
Request URL: https://localhost:44394/get-cidade?search=curvelo
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: [::1]:44394
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Where am I doing wrong? I just need to call the method from my controller by entering the search term via AJAX.

Thanks!

Comment: the "search" parameter is defined to be contained in the URL by your action method whereas the javascript is sending it as query string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select2 settings were correct, the problem was the GetCity method route in the controller, it just worked by removing `{search:regex(^[[a-zA-Z]])}` of the route. The method went like this:

```
[Route("get-cidade")]
public async Task<JsonResult> GetCidade(string search)
{
    var lstCidadesVM = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CidadeViewModel>>(await _cidadeBLL.GetByNome(search));
    return new JsonResult(new { Data = lstCidadesVM });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the route you're implementing is mostly '/get-cidade/curvelo',without any data to transfer as parameter.

Comment: What was sent in the Ajax request was correct, always sent `'/get-city/curvelo'`, the problem was the route of my method in Controller, I posted my solution, anyway thank you very much.